# How to reset a selectbox with jquery using chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I just want to clear the selection of a html selectbox. The following works fine within Safari and Firefox but does not in Google Chrome:

```
$('select#selectbox').val(null);
```

Any ideas?

Whole js here: http://jsfiddle.net/EJgdA/8/

Comment: So you want to un-select the currently selected option or what? This code just sets the value of current option to null.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome 3. What version are you testing with? (Random aside: `select#selectbox` is utterly pointless and is a much slower selector than just `$('#selectbox')` which hooks directly into `document.getElementById()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.val(null)` only seems to work in FF and Opera, so I don't think it's a valid use case.

You can unset everything by using selectedIndex as such:

```
$('#selectbox').prop('selectedIndex', -1);
```

Note that `.prop()` only works in jQuery 1.6+, for lower versions you must use `.attr()`.

Comment: I've tried this on iPads and it doesn't work, but does on iPhones. Tried with `optgroup`s and it works.

Comment: Worth noting that this does reset the `selectedIndex` but if you're using this with combination of `onchange` event, and the previously selected option is selected again, it won't trigger `onchange` in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Have you tried plain js?

```
document.getElementById('selectbox').selectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('select#selectbox').val(null);` returns the value attribute of the selected option, you don't need to add select in your selector.

this will do the trick for you..

```
 $("#selectbox").find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

you van use this line of code also if you have `jQuery1.6`

```
$('#selectbox').prop('selectedIndex', -1);
```

Comment: val(null) does not return the value, it's not the same as val(). Also removeAttr() fails in all browser I tried it in.